# jquery masked input definitions

Tags: jquery, maskedinput

I found this definition as an answer by "popo" to another question:

```
$.mask.definitions['h'] = "^[\\\\/:*?\"<|]?[\\\\/:*?\"<|]*";
           //period was here ^
```

but for some reason this allows periods, even though I removed the period from the definition (it was inside the first opening bracket).

I just want a definition that allows the generic alphanumeric, and some special characters like slashes, dashes, and underscores. How can I change the definition above to do that?

Comment: it should catch periods. did you try doing a hard refresh in your browser? your browser might be caching the previous js.

Comment: hm.. I thought I did. I'll try again

Comment: @mikelt21 nope.. just tried it, restarted the server and browser, still not catching the periods

Comment: okay could you link me to the other question you referenced that regex from?

Comment: @mikelt21 hey sorry for the late response, I was busy yesterday, here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731654/jquery-masked-input-no-illegal-filename-characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need alphanumeric, slash, dash and underscore, then you can use the following:

```
$.mask.definitions['h'] = "[A-Za-z0-9\/\-_]";
```

Comment: why's this adding a big line to the input field? the line disappears where I type text, but the rest of the line stays to the right. The line is showing up when I click on the input field

Comment: is it underscores? like `_____`? does it disappear character by character as your type into the field? if so that's just the placeholder. by default maskedinput uses "_" as the placeholder per character. you can change it when you call the `mask` function by doing something like `$('input').mask({ placeholder: '' })`. that will set the placeholder to be nothing.

Comment: if it's not then could you provide a screen shot of what's going on?

Comment: yea that's what it was, and I'm using the input as a file name, so the file name is coming up as "myFileName________", I'll try the fix you suggested

Comment: wait, I have it right now like this $('input').mask('hhh?hhhhhh'); what would it look like now? would it be  $('input').mask('hhh?hhhhhh', {placeholder: ''})

Comment: oops sorry it should be `$('input').mask('hhh?hhhhhh', {placeholder: ''});`

Comment: no prob! glad to help =) also if your field is for filenames, i don't think filenames allow slashes, at least not in Windows.

Comment: really? I created a file and was renaming and it didn't complain about the dash

Comment: dashes are fine but / is not. you can update your mask to `[A-Za-z0-9\-_]`

Comment: oh slashes, sorry, yea you're right, I changed it earlier when I noticed, but thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: wait a sec, i updated the mask to `[A-Za-z0-9-_]` not `[A-Za-z0-9\-_]` and it was working ok, will that break anything? the numbers maybe? I didn't test numbers... I can't touch the code right now... my boss is demoing the project to the client :\

Comment: that might break the dash. i read that you can only put an _un-escaped_ dash at the beginning or the end of the regex like `[-A-Za-z0-9_]` or `[A-Za-z0-9_-]` for it to work correctly. i just added `\-` just to be extra careful.

Comment: I see, ok, it seems to be working, i can use dash and underscores so thats good